# Is it correct to use “glows” as noun representing more than one “glow”?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> I was so far away, I could hardly *see the nice **glows** of the Christmas lights* decorating the outside of the house.

Is this the correct use of the word *glows*, as a plural for the glow of each of the lights in the decoration?

I intend to use it as plural there — but *glows* also mean non-plural, too, as in something like *the flame glows*. So I'm not sure if the sentence is confusing to the reader. Is this sentence even correct? I think the sentence I give in the box above sounds natural.

Comment: I'm sure that the count usage of glow is acceptable (Anne McCaffrey has sold millions of 'Pern" books), but the normal usage is the non-count one. But you should check for licence for the usage in a dictionary.

Comment: I looked for answer in online  dictionary but yet to find definite answer-they give usage of word glow though

Comment: The sentence ('glows of the... lights') sounds wrong to my (AmE) ears. Usually, lights *glow* (the adjective is not plural.) Lights don't 'shines', they usually don't 'sparkles', etc. The sparkle/twinkling/glow of the lights sounds more natural.

Comment: I know what you means-and that because the example you give glow is put after the words lights ( a different usage-not asked in my question)  so it right to say glow in the  specific case you mention. "Sparkles of a firework"-is probably correct. "Shines of a firework"- is probablly incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED has certainly not got as far as recognising it as countable. None of their examples of the noun contain any plural form.

Comment: @WS2 Could you understand my sentence in the box without confusion?

Comment: @PierreDubois It isn't confusing, but it is not the way a native speaker would say it. It would be "the glow of the Christmas lights". It really stands to reason, *glow* is not something that comes in units, it is a single effect - a bit like *daylight*. One couldn't pluralise that, could one? I acknowledge, however, the exceptions to which Edwin refers below.

Comment: I had in mind that each Christmas decoration each has its own glow.a red bulb and a white bulb each have a glow

Comment: @PierreDubois Yes, as I have commented to Edwin, it is not inconceivable that one could find ways of using the noun in the plural - but it would be very unusual. Usually when a collection of lights glow, the glow is regarded as singular. But one could think of things like *There was a white glow to the left, a red glow to the right and where the **glows** merged, it was pink*.

Comment: @medica Actually it is because you switched it around. In your examples, you’re using _glow/shine/sparkle_ as **verbs**, and since they have auxiliary _do_, they must be in the infinitive no matter if the subject is singular or plural; so “lights don’t glows/shines/sparkles/has” is ungrammatical by definition. In the example in the question, _glow_ is a **noun**, and using it in the plural is perfectly grammatical—just unidiomatic. (Granted, Pierre himself gets verbs and nouns mixed up in the question too: “the nice glows” = plural noun; “the flame glows” = singular verb.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Merci de m'avoir corrigé. Vous avez raison (comme d'habitude!)

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly difficult one to decide correct usage for. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/glow) has the best treatment I've been able to find:

> **glow**  Definitions
>
> 1. countable noun [usu sing]
>
> A glow is a dull, steady light, for example the light produced by a
>   fire when there are no flames.
>
> ⇒ ...*the cigarette's red glow.*
>
> ⇒ *The rising sun casts a golden glow over the fields*.
>
> .......
>
> 2. singular noun
>
> A glow is a pink colour on a person's face, usually because they are
>   healthy or have been exercising.
>
> ⇒ *The moisturiser gave my face a healthy glow that lasted all day*.
>
> .......
>
> > Blockquote
>
> 3. singular noun
>
> If you feel a glow of satisfaction or achievement, you have a strong
>   feeling of pleasure because of something that you have done or that
>   has happened.
>
> [+ of] ⇒ *Exercise will give you a glow of satisfaction at having
>   achieved something.*
>
> [+ of] ⇒ *He felt a glow of pride in what she had accomplished.*

So (1) is the relevant sense (McCaffrey uses 'glows' to mean 'lamps' of a primitive type). But that 'usually singular' caveat is not wonderfully helpful. I'd consider

*The rising sun cast golden glows over the fields on Wednesday and Friday.* unidiomatic;

*The red glows of the cigarettes* marginal; and

*The myriad glows of the fireflies* reasonable and poetic.

The [University of Leicester (or a department thereof)](http://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/press/press-releases/2016/june/glorious-glowing-jupiter-awaits-juno2019s-arrival) seem happy with 'At this wavelength, Jupiter's clouds appear in silhouette against the deep internal glows of the planet. Images of this quality will provide the ...'. It's quite an occasion when astronomers and bards agree on something.

Comment: It uses another idea in your example - it uses putting the word myriad before glows which makes glows sound plural anyway becuase myriad means more than one-I dont use that idea in the sentence I give in my question

Comment: I'd say the 'corporate' non-count _glow_ would be used far more often by Anglophones (than the individualised plural _glows_) in your sentence. But I'd not say the plural usage was unacceptable here.

Comment: I accept that in these rather specialised circumstances, *glows* is a possibility. It is just that the OED has never, it would appear, got around to including them.

Comment: Isn't that because OED doesn't go in for science fiction?

In the context of light cast or thrown or generated by a bulb or lamp or candle, “glows” might just conceivably work as a plural for the separate glow of each of several clearly different lights - say, placed apart in the corners of a large room. It might just be said that something was illuminated by “the glows of 27 candles” but not twice in a year of Sundays…

Singular “glow” would always be preferable as comparable to “light”, not to “lights.”